# How can I change an attribute value of a XML file in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, file, xmldocument

I have a XML file(web.config) and I need to edit the value attribute of each tag, depend of the key name...

this is an example of the XML file:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="A1" value="Hi" />
  <add key="B1" value="Hello" />
</appSettings>
```

I mean, How can I change the value "hi" & "hello" using the key attribute(A1 & B1) ??

Thanks alot

Comment: Why are you programmatically trying to change your .config file?  Perhaps you should take a different approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this code, it works fine:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("Your.xml");
XmlNodeList elementList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("add");
for (int i = 0; i < elementList.Count; i++)
{
    if(elementList[i].Attributes["key"].Value == "A1")
       elementList[i].Attributes["value"].Value = "NewValue";
}
```

Comment: this code is very inefficient since it doesn't utilize any of the Data information that is inherit in XML

Answer (score 1):

if you just want to  edit application configuration file 
this function can help you

```
 private static void SaveConfig(string KeyName, string value)
    {
        System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[KeyName] = value;
        System.Configuration.Configuration config = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath);
        System.Configuration.AppSettingsSection ass = config.AppSettings;
        if (ass.Settings[KeyName] != null)
            ass.Settings[KeyName].Value = value;
        else
            ass.Settings.Add(KeyName, value);
        config.Save();
    }
```

by calling SaveConfig("key","newvalue") you can chage the configvalue

Comment: instead of using System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath youd shoud web.config url

Comment: I think the problem with that, is... I have 2 different projects. the web.config file is in a project & I need to call it from another project... I'm facing before problem with using the configuration class that from it I can deal with web.config easily... since each one reside in a different class, this what make it harder for me. so, I think to do it in another way. Which I think XmlDocument can help me with that much better and in an easy way... So, I did go with it & use XmlDocument...

Thank u soo much guys for your help ;)

Comment: If project A and B are both in the same solution and project A is the default project. But project B is erroring because it is looking for values in the web.config that don't exist because only project A's is being copied over to the bin folder, the easiest thing to do would be to just copy the missing parts from project B's web.config file into project A's.  Though this is more of a hack, it works.